# AWS get instance name in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am developing an application in Java and I am able to list the instances:

```
for (Reservation reservation : result.getReservations()) {
    for (Instance instance : reservation.getInstances()) {
        System.out.println("Instance id:"
                + instance.getInstanceId());
    }
}
```

How do I get the instance name?

Comment: Try [`Instance.getTags()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Instance.html#getTags--).

Comment: Got it. Thanks.Instance.getTags() give list of tags and Tag.value is the instance name.

Comment: @shmosel: Can you please post as an answer for Viswanath to accept so that others can find your solution?

Comment: @DaveMaple I don't know enough to post a substantive answer. Feel free to post one yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access tags associated with the instance:

```
for (Reservation reservation : result.getReservations()) {
    for (Instance instance : reservation.getInstances()) {
        System.out.println("Instance id:" + instance.getInstanceId());

        if (instance.getTags() != null) {
            for (Tag tag : instance.getTags()) {
                System.out.println(String.format(
                    "%s: %s", 
                    tag.getKey(), 
                    tag.getValue()
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an instance name you need to use something like this:

```
        for (Reservation reservation : response.getReservations()) {
            for (Instance instance : reservation.getInstances()) {
                Tag tagName = instance.getTags().stream()
                        .filter(o -> o.getKey().equals("Name"))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(new Tag("Name", "name not found"));

                System.out.println("Found instance with ID: " + instance.getInstanceId()
                        + ", NAME: " + tagName.getValue()
                        + ", TYPE: " + instance.getInstanceType()
                );
            }
        }
```

This way you extract Tag that has key:"Name" and value is what you need.